# Different result running a query in SQL Server and from C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have an app that runs a stored procedure in SQL Server, checking the difference of times between one row in a table and `getdate()`

I call this stored procedure from  c#, and use a `@returnValue` to do some things

This is the method

```
public static bool Check(string CheckStored)
{
    using (DbCommand command = DatabaseDA.DefaultDb.GetStoredProcCommand(CheckStored))
    {
        DatabaseDA.DefaultDb.AddParameter(command, "ReturnValue", DbType.Boolean, ParameterDirection.ReturnValue, "", DataRowVersion.Current, 0);
        DatabaseDA.DefaultDb.ExecuteNonQuery(command);

        return Convert.ToBoolean(command.Parameters["@ReturnValue"].Value);
    }
}
```

and this is the call

```
bool notifNeeded = NotificationsDA.Check("CheckLastEnvioListadoComprobanteEjercicio");
```

then in SQL Server I have:

```
ALTER Procedure [dbo].[CheckLastEnvioListadoComprobanteEjercicio]
as
Begin

declare @UltimoEnvio datetime
declare @ReturnValue bit 
select @UltimoEnvio = LastDate from EnvioListadoEjercicioComprobantes 

Select @returnValue = CASE 
                         WHEN DATEDIFF(hour, @UltimoEnvio, getdate()) >= 1 THEN 1
                         ELSE 0 
                      END   
from rep_inboxRequest

if (@ReturnValue = 1)
    update EnvioListadoEjercicioComprobantes set LastDate = getdate()

return @ReturnValue
END
```

in `EnvioListadoEjercicioComprobantes` I have a row with the lastDate of one action (ej sending mail).

Right now, I have only one row, with `2012-06-18 06:40:02.210` value. I compare this date with the actual date, and return a bit if the difference is more than an hour.

Right now, in Argentina, its about `2012-06-18 11:26`

If I execute `getdate()` in SQL Server, I get `2012-06-18 11:30:44.027`

If I run my entire stored procedure in SQL Server and print `@ReturnValue`, I get 1 and the row is updated-

But when I call my stored from C#, I always get 0, and of course, the row didn't update.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: What debugging steps have you done?

Comment: running step by step. After the `ExecuteNonQuery` I check "Value" and it's 0 (and the convert get a `false`, of course). If I run my stored in SQL server, I get 1 value. Check the app.config, it's the correct database.

Comment: Can you show your connection string? (I have a sneaking suspicion that "user instance" / "AttachDbFilename" are in play.)

Comment: this ? `<add name="GrimPosSuc001" connectionString="Data Source=dsql01.ingematica.local\sql05shared;Initial Catalog=GrimPosSuc001_DESA;User ID=***;Password=****" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />` or you  need entire app.config?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why are you doing all that work (declare, select, update conditionally) when you can just perform a conditional update?

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[CheckLastEnvioListadoComprobanteEjercicio]
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  UPDATE dbo.EnvioListadoEjercicioComprobantes 
    SET LastDate = GETDATE()
    WHERE LastDate <= DATEADD(HOUR, -1, GETDATE());

  IF @@ROWCOUNT > 0
    RETURN 1;
  ELSE
    RETURN 0;
END
GO
```

Anyway I don't think that's the way you deal with a return value. Try something like this (this is pseudo-code):

```cs
DatabaseDA.DefaultDb.ExecuteNonQuery(command);
var returnVal = command.Parameters.Add("@ReturnValue", SqlDbType.Int);
returnVal.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue; // this is important
DatabaseDA.DefaultDb.ExecuteNonQuery(command);
return Convert.ToBoolean(returnVal.Value);
```

Otherwise I suggest you stop using a return value for this, if you want the return parameter to be bit coming out of SQL Server, you can use an output parameter.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[CheckLastEnvioListadoComprobanteEjercicio]
  @ReturnVal BIT = 0 OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  UPDATE dbo.EnvioListadoEjercicioComprobantes 
    SET LastDate = GETDATE()
    WHERE LastDate <= DATEADD(HOUR, -1, GETDATE());

  SELECT @ReturnVal = @@ROWCOUNT;
END
GO
```

Now in your C# code (again, this is pseudo-code, I don't know that it will magically compile in your app if you copy and paste, but it should give you the idea):

```cs
SqlParameter rv = new SqlParameter("@ReturnVal", SqlDbType.Boolean);
rv.Direction=ParameterDirection.Output;
command.Parameters.Add(rv);
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
return Convert.ToBoolean(rv.Value);
```

Comment: If I do `int a = (int)command.Parameters["@ReturnValue"].Value;`. So the problem is that Stored is returning 0, when I need 1.

Comment: I don't think the stored procedure is returning 0. Your C# code isn't properly treating it as a return parameter, so *it* is always changing it to 0. Change your last element in AddWithValue to 1, and I bet you suddenly always get 1.

Comment: Sorry, my english is not very well. What change do you want me to do ? I don't get where my code isn't properly treating  as a return parameter.

Comment: Did you compare your code to mine? Do you see the line where I specify the `Direction` as `ReturnValue`? I even commented it with `// this is important`...

Comment: sorry. I didn't notice that. I will try this now!

Comment: your second block of code doesn't compile. Add method returns an `Int`, so I can set Direction Property. Anyway, I compare that with `AddParameter` method, and the only difference in properties that are setted was the `SQLType`: You put `Int`, I put `Boolean` (because I return a bit). I change that, but in both cases, `ExecuteNonQuery` return 0.
Also try to `command.CreateParameter`, and do the same settings, and didn't work

Comment: A stored procedure can't return a bit. [A stored procedure can only return an int.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174998.aspx) If you want to use a bit, use an output parameter instead of a return value.

Comment: What happens when you change `, 0);` to `, 1);` for `AddParameter`, like I suggested earlier?

Comment: thank's !! This is what I need. Can you add this last comment to your response ? And I will tick it as correct.

Answer (score 0):

Check your database's collation settings: In your Select statement, you are setting `@returnValue` but later you're checking and returning `@ReturnValue`. If case sensitivity is on, those are two different variables.

Comment: I don't think this would explain it, because the procedure wouldn't compile and even if it somehow did the result would be the same in C# and in SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding SET NOCOUNT ON at the top of your stored procedure , traditionally the return value is used to report the number of rows affected using the "SET NOCOUNT ON" option  disables this feature which may be causing trouble with your return value.

Also check the SQL Server Logins Language option as this too can affect the way DateTime is calculated (amongst other things like collation). It might be that in Management Studio you are connecting using a windows account using argentinian local time but the C# application is connecting using a US/English login setting which will cause SQL Server to think you're in a different timezone.

Comment: SQL Server evaluates GETDATE() based on the local server time, not the user. And while I agree about using SET NOCOUNT ON, it is not causing this issue either.